# Validating form values with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have the a form which I want to validate with javascript. My form has two radio buttons to ask the user if he agrees with a certain classification and, if he doesn't he can chose himself a new classification from a drop-down list. In the javascript I want to filter out the invalid combinations of input.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function isValidForm() 
        {

            if(document.validateClassificationForm.acceptclassification.value == 'yes' && document.validateClassificationForm.newclassification.value != 'default')
            {
                if (confirm('You chose the option to accept the classification obtained by the classifier, but you chose another classification from the drop-down list. Do you want to override the classification by the one you chose?')) 
                    return true;
                else 
                    return false;
            }
            if (document.validateClassificationForm.acceptclassification.value == 'no' && document.validateClassificationForm.newclassification.value == 'default') 
            {
                alert('You chose the option not to accept the classification obtained by the classifier. Please chose another classification from the drop-down list.');
                return false;           
            }

            return true;

        }

        </script>
</head>
<body>

<form method=post onsubmit="return isValidForm()" action="index.php?operacao=validateClassification" name="validateClassificationForm">

    <ol> 

    <li><p>Do you agree with the classification attributed to this patient?</p></li>

    <li>Yes<input type="radio" name="acceptclassification" value="yes" checked><br></li>
    <li>No<input type="radio" name="acceptclassification" value="no"></li>

    <li><p>If you don't agree, chose another classification:</p></li>

    <li><label for="newclassification">Chose classification:</label>
    <select name="newclassification">
    <option value="default">Select</option>
    <option value="emergency">Emergency</option>
    <option value="veryurgent">Very urgent</option>
    <option value="urgent">Urgent</option>
    <option value="slightlyurgent">Slightly urgent</option>
    <option value="noturgent">Not urgent</option>
    </select></li>

    <div id="form-button">
    <li><input type="submit" value="Submit"></li>
    </div>

    </ol>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Although, the javascript never seems to be executed and the form is always submited. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`document.validateClassificationForm.acceptclassification` return a ***nodeList*** object. So, you cannot simply write `document.validateClassificationForm.acceptclassification.value`. ***nodeList*** object does not have a property called ***value***.

```
function isValidForm() {
    var acceptclassification = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.validateClassificationForm.acceptclassification).filter(function (element) {
        return element.checked;
    })[0];
    if (acceptclassification.value == 'yes' && document.validateClassificationForm.newclassification.value != 'default') {
        if (confirm('You chose the option to accept the classification obtained by the classifier, but you chose another classification from the drop-down list. Do you want to override the classification by the one you chose?')) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    if (acceptclassification.value == 'no' && document.validateClassificationForm.newclassification.value == 'default') {
        alert('You chose the option not to accept the classification obtained by the classifier. Please chose another classification from the drop-down list.');
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

Check it on http://jsfiddle.net/4n8S6/